# Rails: find records with has_one relationship

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-4

i have a user model that has many designs and also has_many design_request through designs

Now my design_request model has_one order. how can i get all the design requests with the order state == "paid" for a user

```
my user model is below 
  ##User Model
  has_many :designs
  has_many :design_requests, through: :designs

  ##Design Model
  has_many :design_requests

 ##Design Request Model
   belongs_to :design
  belongs_to :user
  validates :business_name, :design_id, presence: true
  delegate :name, to: :design
  has_one :order, as: :item
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried something like:

```
user.design_requests.includes(:order).where(orders: {state: "paid"})
```

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?
user.design_requests.select {|dr| dr.order.state == "paid"}